# Build Swift 3 in Terminal to create XCode project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

It seems Apple changed this line:

```
swift build -X
```

This no longer works to create an Xcode project as described [here](https://medium.com/@joannis.orlandos/using-mongokitten-vapor-for-your-applications-24dbac2f5dd9#.7621vgugl)

Doest anyone know the updated way to do this as I cannot find it online
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now you should use the Swift Package Manager.

To create a project structure:

```
swift package init --type executable
```

or

```
swift package init --type library
```

To make a project compatible with Xcode:

```
swift package generate-xcodeproj
```